# Need a good way to manage my projects' task lists and information

Tags: project-management, information-management

My old system involved using Microsoft FrontPage and a frame page.  The top frame contained a (tree) list of the tasks and sub-tasks I'd need to do, while the bottom frame contained any useful project information, notes, etc. I'd invariably need to jot down.  I used bookmarks in the page to mark major tasks while highlighting current tasks with bold and marking off finished ones with italic.  I would use a third frame for navigating between bookmarks via. a Table of Contents of hyperlinks linking to them.  It was pretty clumsy, but it worked nicely.

Obviously, I want to upgrade now.  Any good ideas on how to get a new system in place that can do something similar to my old one (without the crudeness/clumsiness)?  That is, a formal piece of software for that purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ToDoList](http://www.abstractspoon.com/tdl_resources.html) is pretty good. Cons: Windows-only.

Comment: Interesting.  Let's see if this does what I need...

Comment: It's good, but I'm having trouble making effective use of it.

Answer (score 3):

We use [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/), and it's worked out brilliantly for us. Far better than JIRA, easy to use,  friendly, powerful. Highly recommend it.

- It has a built-in wiki for notes.
  (Really easy to use!)
- It has a bug tracking system that is
  second to none.
- You can even make your software
  submit its error reports to FogBugz,
  and it will automatically generate a
  case with relevant information in it.
  This feature is called Scout.
- You can create releases and all file
  cases, features, bugs, whatever by
  release, priority, etc. the power is
  all there.
- And best of all, you can host it on
  your own server or have them host it
  for you. Nifty system.
- Works on just about any OS and browser.
- Unlike most web applications, it's snappy!

Comment: It should be mentioned that it's not free.

Comment: @dehmann - they offer a "Student and Startup" edition that is free for 2 users

Answer (score 2):

We are using [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) for task lists, version planning and time management. And [Google sites](http://sites.google.com/) for internal documentation and related things. In general most Wiki system  will be good for the documentation and todo (e.g. [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/default2.jsp)).

Answer (score 1):

**[TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/default.aspx) : Team Foundation System**

Full source control & work item tracking all integrated with Visual Studio.

If you use Visual Studio, and work in a windows environment, I recommend this.
If you don't use Visual Studio I recommend you do ;)

You can also setup project portals etc. that display activity, reports, all that jazz.

Answer (score 1):

[Basecamp](http://www.basecamphq.com) from 37signals is a great tool to keep track of your tasks and projects.

Answer (score 0):

I use [fogbugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/) s&s edition

Answer (score 0):

I think that an *Issue Tracking System* may suite your needs, there are [plenty alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems) from OpenSource to Commercial...

Answer (score 0):

You can setup and use [ASP.NET Time Tracker Starter Kit](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/time-tracker/). It also allows you to extend it.